# Showing that two equations are equal using chain rule.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $u = f(x,y)$, with $x= r \cos\theta$, $y =r\sin\theta$.
>   Show that $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2$$

How do I solve this question when the equation of $u$ is not given? I know that to get $\left(\dfrac{du}{dr}\right)^{2}$, I would first need to get $\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}\right)$ because

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$

Also what do the squares on the partial derivatives imply? Do they to just do a simple square of the values or do they mean more? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Leave the derivatives you don't know explicitly as variables

Comment: @DanZimm What do you mean? $(du/dx)$ is equal to $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x= r \cos\theta$ , $y= r \sin\theta$

Using

> $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\quad\text{and} \quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$

We have

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\cos\theta+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\sin\theta$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot(-r\sin\theta)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot(r\cos\theta)$$

By squaring these two equations we get

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)^2=&\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot\cos\theta+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\sin\theta\right)^2\\
=&\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2\cdot\cos^2\theta+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\cdot\sin^2\theta+2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\sin\theta\cos\theta\tag{1}\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)^2&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\cdot(-\cos\theta)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot\sin\theta\right)^2\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2\cdot\sin^2\theta+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\cdot\cos^2\theta-2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\sin\theta\cos\theta\tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2$$

Comment: I don't understand. This is what I wrote above. How do I manipulate these?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Please give me a moment to digest this. I'll let you know if I can't solve it myself. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a minor thing but isn't $(dx/dr) = cos\theta$?

Comment: so for the $(a+b)^{2}$ I got $cos^{2}\theta (dy/dx)^{2} + sin\theta cos\theta (du/dx)(du/dy) + sin^{2}\theta(du/dy)^{2}$ Where do I go from here? Did I do it right?

Comment: Where does the 2 come from? I don't have similar equations to add together. Multiplying $(du/dx)⋅cosθ$ and $(du/dy)⋅sinθ$ only gives $sinθcosθ(du/dx)(du/dy)$ right?

Comment: @i=Integrator But isn't that only true if both a and b have the same variables, which in this case it isn't? Sorry for bothering you but could you please give the solution to the problem? I think I might understand the question better if I see the whole process. Thanks!

Comment: Is the 2 always used in general? How different is this from foiling a general equation. ie. $(x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} = x^{2}y^{2} + x^{2}y^{2} + y^{2}$ and $(x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} = x^{2}y^{2} + 2 x^{2}y^{2} + y^{2}$. The first equation is the right one, right? If it is, where does the 2 come in?